# Integration of arctan(x) is itself?

Tags: integration, trigonometry

Sorry if this seems like a useless question, but I can't seem to work out what's wrong with the following reasoning, which leads to what is definitely an incorrect answer.

so,
$$
\int \arctan(x) dx = x \arctan(x) - \int \frac{x}{1+x^2}dx
$$

Pretty standard so far, then instead of using substitution to evaluate the second integral, I used integration by parts again:

$$
\int \frac{x}{1+x^2}dx=x \int \frac{1}{1+x^2}dx - \int \frac{1}{1+x^2}dx
$$

Which should be true, but must be where the problem is because this leads to

$$
x \arctan(x) - \arctan(x)
$$

which implies

$$
\int \arctan(x) dx = \arctan(x)
$$

Which is clearly wrong as arctan tends to a value whereas the areas under the curve does not, plus loads of other reasons why this is clearly a mistake.

Can somebody help me find out where I've gone wrong

Comment: $$\int \frac{x}{1+x^2}dx\color{red}{\neq}x \int \frac{1}{1+x^2}dx - \int \frac{1}{1+x^2}dx$$

Comment: By the way, I knew how the problem should be solved but wanted to see why this wasn't working. I know now, I guess I'll leave this up in case someone else has the same problem? If people think I should take it down I'm fine with that.

Comment: If you find an answer to your question, *post it as an answer*. Don't edit it *into* the question.

Comment: okay, that's done now

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Just so this question can be answered:

You originally did the integration by parts incorrectly:

$u=x,\ \ \ \ \ dv=\frac{1}{1+x^2}dx$

$du=dx,\ \ \ \ \ v=\int\frac{1}{1+x^2}dx$

$$\int\frac{x}{1+x^2}dx=x\int\frac{1}{1+x^2}dx-\int\left(\int\frac{1}{1+x^2}dx \right)dx$$

Answer (score 7):

You can't take the $x$ out of the first integral on the right side because $x$ is the integration variable and is not a constant. You would have to handle it differently like this: Let $u = 1+x^2$, and can you continue to the finish?

Comment: I'm not taking it out as a constant, thats the other part of the integration by parts.

Answer (score 3):

we have $$\int \frac{x}{1+x^2}dx=\frac{1}{2}\int \frac{2x}{1+x^2}dx$$

Comment: Indeed, one should immediately recognise that the second integral is (1/2) ln (1 + x^2) + C. After all, the numerator x is "almost" equal to the derivative of the denominator 1 + x^2.

Answer (score -2):

I figured out the problem pretty much as soon as I posted this, the second integral is a double integral, i.e.

$$
\int \frac{x}{1+x^2}dx=x \int \frac{1}{1+x^2}dx - \int \int \frac{1}{1+x^2}dx^2
$$

Which leads to

$$
\int \arctan(x) dx =x \arctan(x) - x \arctan(x) - \int \arctan(x) dx
$$

Comment: You are using symbols incorrectly. The object $$\int \int \frac{1}{1+x^2}dx^2$$ is undefined and not relevant to integration by parts formulas (which you seem to be trying to use here).

Comment: I mean to say that it's integrated twice, how would you recommend writing this?

Comment: You can write it as $\int(\int\frac{1}{1 + x^2}dx)dx$. Use the parentheses to make sure the $dx$ isn't mixed up with the inner integral expression. like [this other answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/1757071/556042), which I suggest you should accept as the answer.